# Clearly stating assemblies for auto-registration

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

Our application uses Autofac as the IoC container and takes advantage of auto-registration for a few assemblies that contain widely used code.

To reference each assembly, one would normally use `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(<type>))`, using one of the types in the respective assembly. That is, however, not very clear, because it's not easy to see which assembly is registered via each type, and it can also lead to errors when types are moved between projects.

To solve this, in each assembly in question, I created an empty class called `Types` that of course has the assembly's namespace, so I can do the auto-registration like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(
    Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Xx.Common.Types)),
    Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Xx.Core.Types)),
    Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Xx.Infrastructure.Types)))
    .AsSelf()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

This is of course "dead code" otherwise. Is it a good or "clever" idea to do it this way, or is there a better, more idiomatic one? Am I dumb for even bothering to ask about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're doing is actually quite clever. The approach I take is similar, but instead of creating a new type, I point at an existing type (like you did), but fully quality its name, as follows:

```cs
typeof(global::Company.Product.BusinessLayer.ICommandHandler<>).Assembly
```

This makes it really clear that we're targeting the business layer here and if the type in question is moved to another project, there will be a compile error in here.